# Парсер страниц с JS

Tags: php, парсер, curl, download

Есть парсер на CURL  но он работает только со статическими страницами.

Нужен парсер что б работал с динамикой (то есть стягивал динамически сформированный контент). Сайт для  [примера](http://brb.to/).

Какие инструменты сейчас используют для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Минимум нужен движок который обрабатывает Javascript. 
В самом простом решении берут браузер и работают с ним через Selenium или через API.

Хотя есть решения работающие через консоль, например PhantomJs, и [соответствующая библиотек](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)а для работы с ним через PHP

> PhantomJS это что-то типа браузера (на основе webkit), только с
>   управлением из консоли, поддержкой CSS, DOM и конечно JavaScript.