# Можно ли парсить сайт динамично? Если да, то как?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Можно ли парсить сайт динамично?

Например. При вводе, в поле поиска, буквы или слова... . Выскакивающий список подсказок, допустимых слов и фраз, меняется в зависимости от написания каждой буквы. Так вот, мне нужно динамично подтягивать этот список к себе на сайт. Возможно ли это сделать и как?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579406/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86-%d1%81-js/579409#579409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS для этого нужен или Selenium но задачка не из простых и повозится с их настройкой придётся изрядно.